# Mysql query, max and min values in a range doesn't get the proper output

Tags: mysql, max, inner-join, between

I have a table called "dati" with the column "anni" (primary key) that represents the years from 1960 to 2012 (all the years are consecutives), the column "governi" represents the REFERENCE to the table "governi" and the column "pil" are the values I want to exctract with the values inside the column "presidenti" in the table "governi".
If i try to extract min/max value for all years it works. But in this case i need to extract this values in a restricted range of years (for example from 1980 to 1990). And the problem is that doesn't return any max/min value.
Table "dati" and table "governi" are connected between column "governo" and column "cod" as you can see in the database schema.

This is the database structure:

```
TABLE dati:
    anno INT(4),
    governo VARCHAR(6),
    pil FLOAT(10)
TABLE governi:
    cod VARCHAR(6),
    presidente varchar (50)
```

This is the SQL:

query1:

```
SELECT a.presidente, b.anno, b.$dato
FROM governi AS a
INNER JOIN dati AS b ON a.cod=b.governo
WHERE b.$dato =(
    SELECT MAX(c.$dato) AS maxpil
    FROM dati AS c
) AND b.anno BETWEEN $inizio AND $fine;
```

query2:

```
SELECT a.presidente, b.anno, b.$dato
FROM governi AS a
INNER JOIN dati AS b ON a.cod=b.governo
WHERE b.$dato = (
    SELECT MIN(NULLIF(c.$dato,0)) AS valore
    FROM dati AS c
) AND b.anno BETWEEN $inizio AND $fine;
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: this has nothing to do with PHP. This is purely an SQL construction problem. I've ripped out the irrelevant PHP code and left only the sql.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or and sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: A question properly formed contains the seeds of the answer.There is a strong correlation between the quality of the question and the inability to find the answer.

Comment: I think the problem is my bas explanation of the question?...

Comment: ...Sorry for my bad english. I have tried to upload the table and the query on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a57ee/1

Comment: I try to explain better my question..My problem is that i have to extract the MAX and MIN value from a query that includes an INNER JOIN and a "BETWEEN clause".

Comment: So what do you want to happen if the MIN or MAX are not in the range?

Comment: I read for another time my question and i think i can do it better for explain my problem: for example if i have a table with primary key year (from 1960 to 2010)and for all years i have value number(for example 300 is the value associated for year 1960 and 250 is the value associated for year 1975), my query calculate the max and the min of a value of all this values(range from 1960 to 2010). And the result should be the max is: 300 for 1960 and the min:250 for 1975. My problem is that when i try to restric my range search (for example from 1980 to 1990) it doesn't return the min/max value.

Comment: I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: @GiulioBambini So why dont you select MIN and MAX from that range,not from the whole table?

Comment: @Mihai Can you write me the correct query please?

Comment: @Marc B? @ Strawberry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.presidente, b.anno, b.$dato
FROM governi AS a
INNER JOIN dati AS b ON a.cod=b.governo
WHERE b.$dato =(
    SELECT MAX($dato) AS maxpil
    FROM dati,governi WHERE anno BETWEEN $inizio AND $fine AND governi.cod=dati.govern
)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5adf7/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a.presidente, b.anno, q.valore, q.maxpil
FROM governi AS a
INNER JOIN dati AS b ON a.cod=b.governo
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(anno) AS maxpil,
           MIN(anno) AS valore
    FROM dati AS c
    WHERE c.anno BETWEEN 
             1965    -- $inizio 
          AND 
             2012    -- $fine
) AS q
ON b.anno BETWEEN q.valore AND q.maxpil
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/480e9/14